# Make my raster extract R code more efficient?

Tags: r, spatial, raster, data-extraction

Could someone help me make my code below more efficient please? As the datasets are very large, running the extract(raster, polygon) section each time is very slow. I think they can be combined so it's only done once but I'm struggling with how to do that.

```
result$mean   <- extract(raster, polygons, weights=T, na.rm=F, fun=mean)
result$cells  <- unlist(lapply(extract(raster, polygons, weights=T, na.rm=F), 
                        FUN = function(x)(length(x[,1]))))
results$zeros <- unlist(lapply(extract(raster, polygons, weights=T, na.rm=F), 
                        FUN = function(x)(sum(x[,1]==0))))
```

Answer (score 3):

When working with `extract` and `SpatialPolygons` you can make use of the **built-in parallelization** of the `raster` package. As we learn from `?raster::clusterR`:

> "The use of the cluster is automatic in these functions: `projectRaster`, `resample` and in `extract` when using polygons."

Thus you can extremely speed up your process by calling

```
library(raster)
beginCluster()
```

in the beginning.

*Note:*  don't forget to close the cluster after you are done.

```
endCluster()
```